# How come multiple classes not targeting in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use validate_empty_field function for both classes .log and .log2. For some reason only .log is targeted but .log2 textarea is not. When you click on text area, if empty, both should show validation error if the other one is empty or if both empty.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#field-warning-message').hide();
    $('#dob-warning-message').hide();

    var empty_field_error = false;
    var dob_error = false;
//    $('input[type=text], textarea')
    $('.log, .log2').focusout(function () {
        validate_empty_field();
    });

    function validate_empty_field() {
        var field = $('.log, .log2, textarea').val();
//        var first_name_regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]{3,15}$/;
        if (field.length == '') {
            $('#field-warning-message').show();
            $('#field-warning-message').html("Please fill out form!");
            empty_field_error = true;
        } else if (field.length < 1) {
            $('#field-warning-message').show();
            $('#field-warning-message').html("Please fill out form!");
            empty_field_error = true;
        } else {
            $('#field-warning-message').hide();
        }
    }

    $('.verify-form').submit(function () {
        empty_field_error = false;
        dob_error = false;

        validate_empty_field();

        if ((empty_field_error == false) && (dob_error == false)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="log"></textarea>
<textarea class="log2"></textarea>
<div id="field-warning-message"></div>
```

Comment: because `var field = $('.log, .log2, textarea').val();` does not give you value for each, it returns the first value it finds. You will have to loop over each element and check the value.

Comment: So could I just use one class .log, apply that class to any field, and loop over it?

Comment: `field.length == ''` will never succeed. It should be either `field === ''` or `field.length === 0`. Also, you can just `return !empty_field_error && !dob_error;` instead of the `if/else` block you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the event to the handler so you have access to the target

Change your event listener line to this:

`$('.log1, .log2').focusout(validate_empty_field);`

and then accept an argument in `validate_empty_field`

```
function validate_empty_field(ev){
    var field = $(ev.target).val();
    if(!field.length){
        //textarea is empty!
    }else{
        //textarea is not empty!
    }
}
```

in fact, you could do all of this in an anonymous function you have already created, and use the `on` method to stick with JQuery best practices:

```
$('.log1, .log2').on('focusout', function(){
    if(!$(this).val().length){
        //this textarea is empty
    }else{
        //this textarea is not empty!
    }
});
```

And yes, adding one class to all textareas and swapping out `.log1, .log2` for that class would be a better option.

EDIT: Final option should cover all requirements.

```
$('.log').on('focusout', function(){
    $('.log').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val().length){
            //this textarea is empty
        }else{
            //this textarea is not empty!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried the first set of code you have and it works but not if both are empty. Also noticed error only triggers if input clicked again vs clicking off the other input.

Comment: Oh, I missed the party where you wanted to validate every field every time, I'll add a final example